# How to get list of fields from Object in mongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm new in mongoDB, I saw enough examples but most show how to work with collections.

I have followed data stored in mongoDB under DB name `myDB`:

```
"_id" : "some_table_name",
"content" : [{
  "id" : "1",
  "loctype" : "Clinic/Hospital",
  "locname" : "KKH"
}, {
  "id" : "2",
  "loctype" : "Clinic/Hospital",
  "locname" : "Singapore National Eye Centre"      
 }
 }]
}
```

As you can see the model contains `_id` and `content`, where `content` is list of objects:

```
  ... ,
 {
  "id" : "ZZZ",
  "loctype" : "ZZZ",
  "locname" : "ZZZ"      
  },
  ...
```

**PHP**

```
$m = new MongoClient(/* ... */);

$db = $m->myDB;

$collection = $db->coll;
```

**How can I fetch in PHP list of ids?** a.e `[1,2]` in my case.

For sure I can get all model and extract ids but I try to do it stright from mongoDB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want this formatted but here is a aggregation version which formats it in a nice way:

```
$mongo->collection->aggregate(array(
    array('$unwind'=>'$content'),
    array('$project'=>array('_id'=>'$content.id'))
))
```

It will print documents like:

```
[
    {_id:1},
    {_id:2}
]
```

Another way could be to just project the single field out with `$db->collection->find(array(),array('content.id'=>1))`

I should note though, it would most likely to better to just do this in PHP. Through PHP is the only way you can get the exact output you are seeking I believe.

Comment: @MaximShoustin True, converted to PHP

Comment: @MaximShoustin There is a serious troll some where, I get a lot of answers downvoted recently, it is rather annoying `:/`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'collection_name');

$query = array(
// Some restrictions can be here
);

$ids    = array();
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    $doc = (array) $doc;
    $ids[] = $doc["id"];
}

var_dump($ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mapreduce followed by distinct, as follows:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "things",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "things" + "_keys"
})
db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
["foo", "bar", "baz", "_id", ...]
```

Or use [Variety](https://github.com/variety/variety)...